# How can I create a meta_query with an array of dates?

Tags: meta-query

How can I create a `meta_query` with an array of dates to retrieve only rows where date is more than `NOW()`?

Comment: Do you mean the meta values are stored as an array? Or are you trying to find single meta values and compare them to more than one date? Are the meta values stored as MYSQL timestamps?

Comment: @WebElaine Thanks for your reply. Yes, I mean the meta values are stored as an array of timestamps

Comment: There's no way to sort in the query itself. You'll have to pull all the data and then use PHP to sort through it. Or, change the data structure so you insert one db row for each value - that way they're single values, even though each post can have multiple values for that key, if that makes sense.

Comment: @WebElaine, thanks a lot. I've done it in this way. Filling my array field with dates I'm finding the biggest date and put it in the separate field. And then I can easily retrieve and sort rows by this new field.